# Best way to plug users' gmail accounts into my system without triggering ominous warnings?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, google-account

I am prototyping an automated messaging system with a few pilot companies and about 10 users. They want my system to send status emails on their behalf, from their gmail accounts. This can easily be accomplished when they enter their gmail usn/pwd into my system (it is AES 256-bit encrypted before being stored in the DB). The problem is that the first time my system tries to send a status email on their behalf, using their account, the message is blocked until "Allow less secure apps" is enabled. When they try again, it's blocked again, along with scary warnings being emailed to them by google saying that someone has their google password. Only after they click through that and verify that my system has permission to do this, all is good, no more warnings, and everything works.

I have been researching this and I have found 2 potential approaches for smoothing this process and avoiding the scary warnings to the users:

1. Enable 2-factor authentication in the google account, and use an app-specific password (per user I think??) to send the emails without any warnings.
2. Have my system use oauth2 with the gmail accounts so that google no longer considers my app "less secure".

My question is, *what is the best approach, and how do I set this up*? If my gmail users enable 2-factor authentication, can they store their code into my system, and my system uses that code for future auto-emails? Does it even work that way? My experience with 2-factor auth is that a code is sent to the user's phone each and every time. Is that not the case? Would a stored code on my server (1 per user) work over and over? Does it expire after a certain amount of time?

And my understanding with oauth2 is that my users would need to be actively logged in with their google account and somehow exchange tokens with my server, but I really don't know. Is there some way for my web server (PHP) to implement oauth2 in connection with gmail accounts?

In summary, *what is the simplest way to send auto-generated gmails for my users* who are paying for this service without triggering scary warnings from google? The volume of emails is low -- this isn't spam -- it's a status follow-up system for the workplace.

Answer (score 0):

You are right on your second point; that is an easy way to accomplish your objectives. You'll first have to [authorize your app with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth) to work with [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). You can follow these links to learn how to implement authorization in your server, but you can also enter [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) to appreciate some examples. When you develop the authorization protocol, you can read the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) to start working with your customer accounts.